# How to install Kernel Modules to lib/modules/ from Kernel-Source

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Got a Kernel-Source and I want to install the Modules to my ARM-System to the path lib/modules. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can place them in a directory in /lib/modules. Then you will need to edit /etc/depmod.conf to make the kernel use them on boot. Then run the depmod command to make these changes take effect. If you want to load them immediately, you will have to use the modprobe command.

Comment: Ty for ur answer. I have got modules in my lib/modules folder with the kernel version of it. not sure if I load the right ones. How can I make sure that I am using the right ones or even one? Please explain in little steps, really newb in linux.

Comment: If you want to make sure you are using the right module, run "modinfo blah" where blah is the name of module. Pay attention to the path it returns. If it isn't the right module, then you need to edit /etc/depmod.conf and maybe something under /etc/depmod.d/

Comment: I even don´t know which module I´m looking for, so i don´t know what to type after modinfo. I just know I have to use the modules. I have got 3 different(kernel version) folder in lib/modules. I don´t have any depmod.conf. also checked the whole system for this conf. There is just ubuntu.conf in /etc/depmod.d/ with no important content

Comment: Maybe you should build the kernel you got along with the modules and do a standard kernel and module install. I don't think you want to load them individually with your currently running kernel. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile

Comment: That seems to be very complex and not specified for ARM-Systems. Maybe first I should check if there are any modules installed/used?

Comment: A kernel for ARM systems won't be built in a different way than say other architectures. If you want to see what modules are in use, use the command lsmod.